# Is this snippet legal Standard ML according to the Definition?

Tags: language-lawyer, sml, polyml, mosml

Is the code snippet given below legal Standard ML according to the Definition? It type-checks with Poly/ML, but not with Moscow ML:

```
infixr 5 ::: ++

signature HEAP_ENTRY =
sig
  type key
  type 'a entry = key * 'a

  val reorder : ('a -> key) -> 'a * 'a -> 'a * 'a
end

signature HEAP_TAIL =
sig
  structure Entry : HEAP_ENTRY

  type 'a tail

  val empty : 'a tail
  val cons : 'a Entry.entry * 'a tail -> 'a tail
  val uncons : 'a tail -> ('a Entry.entry * 'a tail) option
  val ++ : 'a tail * 'a tail -> 'a tail
end

signature SIMPLE_FOREST =
sig
  structure Entry : HEAP_ENTRY

  type 'a tree
  type 'a tail = (int * 'a tree) list

  val head : 'a tree -> 'a Entry.entry
  val tail : int * 'a tree -> 'a tail
  val cons : 'a Entry.entry * 'a tail -> 'a tail
  val link : (int * 'a tree) * 'a tail -> 'a tail
end

structure IntRank =
struct
  fun reorder f (x, y) = if f x <= f y then (x, y) else (y, x)

  fun relabel' (_, nil, ys) = ys
    | relabel' (r, x :: xs, ys) =
      let val r = r - 1 in relabel' (r, xs, (r, x) :: ys) end

  fun relabel (r, xs) = relabel' (r, xs, nil)
end

functor SimpleForestTail (F : SIMPLE_FOREST) :> HEAP_TAIL
  where type Entry.key = F.Entry.key =
struct
  open F

  val empty = nil

  fun link ((x, xs), ys) = F.link (x, xs ++ op:: ys)
  and xs ++ nil = xs
    | nil ++ ys = ys
    | (op:: xs) ++ (op:: ys) = link (IntRank.reorder (#1 o #1) (xs, ys))

  fun pick args = #1 (Entry.reorder (#1 o head o #2 o #1) args)
  fun attach (x, (y, xs)) = (y, x :: xs)
  fun extract (xs as (x, op:: ys)) = pick (xs, attach (x, extract ys))
    | extract xs = xs

  fun rebuild (x, xs) = (head (#2 x), tail x ++ xs)
  fun uncons xs = Option.map (rebuild o extract) (List.getItem xs)
end
```

The error Moscow ML gives is:

```
File "test.sml", line 47-66, characters 45-631:
! .............................................:> HEAP_TAIL
!   where type Entry.key = F.Entry.key =
! struct
!   open F
! ..........
!   
!   fun rebuild (x, xs) = (head (#2 x), tail x ++ xs)
!   fun uncons xs = Option.map (rebuild o extract) (List.getItem xs)
! end
! Signature mismatch: the module does not match the signature ...
! Scheme mismatch: value identifier uncons
! is specified with type scheme 
!   val 'a' uncons :
  (int * 'a' tree) list -> ((key * 'a') * (int * 'a' tree) list) option
! in the signature
! but its declaration has the unrelated type scheme 
!   val uncons :
  (int * 'a tree) list -> ((key * 'a) * (int * 'a tree) list) option
! in the module
! The declared type scheme should be at least as general as the specified type scheme
```

I tried using an explicit type signature for `uncons`:

```
  fun 'a uncons (xs : 'a tail) = Option.map (rebuild o extract) (List.getItem xs)
```

But it merely makes the error message more localized:

```
File "test.sml", line 65, characters 78-80:
!   fun 'a uncons (xs : 'a tail) = Option.map (rebuild o extract) (List.getItem xs)
!                                                                               ^^
! Type clash: expression of type
!   (int * 'a tree) list
! cannot have type
!   (int * 'b tree) list
! because of a scope violation:
! the type variable 'a is a parameter 
! that is declared within the scope of 'b
```

If anyone's interested, here's [where the snippet originally came from](https://github.com/eduardoleon/typhoon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the use of `#1` in line 57. It involves a locally unresolved record type. The SML definition says that "the program context must uniquely determine" how to resolve such a type and that a type annotation may be required. Unfortunately, the definition doesn't say how large the relevant program context may be. No implementation accepts an arbitrary large context, and no complete efficient algorithm has been published that could handle that, short of introducing record polymorphism (and thus being too general). So not being more specific is considered a (known) bug in the definition.

A good rule of thumb for what works across all implementations is the smallest surrounding declaration, i.e., in this case the definition of `++`. The type of `#1` cannot be determined from that definition alone, so many implementations will reject it even though some are more lenient.

Comment: Defining an auxiliary `type 'a front = (int * 'a tree) * 'a tail`, and annotating `fun pick args : 'a front = #1 ...` solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Another possible fix was, without defining an auxiliary type, to mark `pick` and `extract` as mutually recursive.